# SimpleDateFormat is not working as expected

Tags: java, date, time, date-format, simpledateformat

I am using "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" to initialize SimpleDateFormat.setLenient option is set false.
Below are some use cases

1)input String:-01/02/2001 3:09 AM
expected:-should pass
actual:-passes

2)input String:-01/02/20016 3:09 AM
expected:-should NOT pass
actual:-passes
I don't understand why 20016 is parsed as valid one!!!!!

Comment: java.text.SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
dateFormat.parse("01/02/20016 3:09 AM");                                                                This should throw exception but it does not.

Comment: Why should the above code throw exception ?

Comment: Bcoz 20016 is not in yyyy format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Peter and mprivat, but if you really need to do this a solution could be:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a") {
        public synchronized Date parse(String source) throws ParseException {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date d = super.parse(source);
            cal.setTime(d);
            if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) > 9999 ) {
                throw new ParseException("Year too long", 11);
            }
            return d;
        };
    };
```

Comment: if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) > 9999 || cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) < 1000)            this modification would ensure yyyy format

Comment: That's a nice clean way to add the logic inside the formatter. Like it. +1

Answer (score 6):

I think it's in the Javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat`:

**Year**: For formatting, if the number of pattern letters is 2, the year is truncated to 2 digits; otherwise it is interpreted as a number.

So basically, you can constrain it to 2, but otherwise, it's an int. So 4-y does not mean exactly 4, it's just "not 2".

Comment: Really gr8 info.But is it possible to return false in case of "01/02/20016 3:09 AM" using sdf or regex remains only other option?

Comment: Regex is probably your only option. But I'd suspect you might want to assert that the year is less than whatever limit your requirements set instead of asserting that the string representing the year is 4 digits. By that, I mean that you should parse the Date, then check the year of the date object.

Answer (score 2):

Its about 18000 years in the future. Passes all scientific logic.
So why should the year 20016 NOT be latient?  :)

(Remember SDF should be marked as deprecated, because not thread-safe)

Comment: Because I've specified yyyy format.Try 113 as month.This would throw parseException.

Comment: well, :D there is no month 113 but year 20016 should be ok

Comment: no. but after 18000 years from now, there should be a function called set3DigitYearStart analouge to set2DigitYearStart.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not deprecated.

Comment: well, it should be deprecated.